# The integration domain of multivariable functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If I would like to evaluate integral of function $f(\eta_{11},\eta_{12},\eta_{21},\eta_{22})$ in a space that meets all of the following conditions,
\begin{equation}
  \frac{2}{3} > \eta_{11} > \eta_{12} > 0 \\
  \frac{2}{3} > \eta_{11} > \eta_{21} > 0 \\
  \frac{1}{3} > \eta_{21} > \eta_{22} > 0 \\
  \frac{1}{3} > \eta_{12} > \eta_{22} > 0 \\
\end{equation}
what integration should I calculate?

**Generalization**

Actually, the above discussion is a special case of the below. Here, $\eta$ matrix whose index begin from $0$.
\begin{equation}
\eta = \begin{pmatrix}
\eta_{00} & \eta_{10} && \cdots && \eta_{0,n-1} \\
\eta_{10} & \eta_{11} && \cdots && \eta_{1,n-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots && \vdots && \vdots \\
\eta_{0,n-1} & \eta_{0,n} && \cdots && \eta_{n-1,n-1} \\
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^{n \times n}
\end{equation}

elements of $\eta$ have to be satisfied with

\begin{equation}
\eta_{i-1,j} > \eta_{i,j} \\
\eta_{i,j-1} > \eta_{i,j} \\
\end{equation}

And we define
\begin{equation}
\eta_{0i}=\eta_{i0}=\frac{n-i}{n}.
\end{equation}
for $i\in\{0,1,\cdots,n-1\}$

Then, I have to evaluate the integration of function $f(\eta) = f(\eta_{00},\cdots, \eta_{n-1,n-1})$,

\begin{equation}
  \int_\eta f(\eta) {\ \rm d}\eta.
\end{equation}

In case of $n=3$,
\begin{equation}
\eta = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2/3 & 1/3 & \\
2/3 & \eta_{11} &  \eta_{12}\\
1/3 & \eta_{21} &  \eta_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^{3 \times 3}
\end{equation}

Then,
\begin{equation}
  \frac{2}{3} > \eta_{11} > \eta_{12} > 0 \\
  \frac{2}{3} > \eta_{11} > \eta_{21} > 0 \\
  \frac{1}{3} > \eta_{21} > \eta_{22} > 0 \\
  \frac{1}{3} > \eta_{12} > \eta_{22} > 0 \\
\end{equation}

Now, I would like to evaluate the integration of function $f(\eta) = f(\eta_{11},\eta_{12},\eta_{21},\eta_{22})$ in the above region. How can I write the integration in a line?

Comment: Your first integration is wrong. We should fix that before you move on to other ones. It can either be $$\int_0^1 d\eta_4 \int_0^{\eta_4} d\eta_3 \int_0^{\eta_3} d\eta_2\int_0^{\eta_2} f \:d\eta_1$$ or $$\int_0^1 d\eta_1 \int_{\eta_1}^1 d\eta_2 \int_{\eta_2}^1 d\eta_3 \int_{\eta_3}^1 f \:d\eta_4$$ if you want to do it in one integral.

Comment: Also you should check your conditions for the new one. As written, they are either redundant or not what you actually want to calculate because the inequalities, while not technically incorrect look very suspiciously like work gone wrong.

Comment: Ninad Munshi   Thank you. I modified.

Comment: Calum Gilhooley Thank you. The condition was wrong. I modified.

Comment: The condition was wrong. I modified.

Comment: @CalumGilholey Oh.. I did not know it. Thank you!!

Comment: I'm sure there are several ways to write it, but most likely all of them will involve splitting the domain into cases and summing the integrals over distinct domains. For some calculations, using the $\min$ or $\max$ functions in the domain limits could be a useful shortcut, but that's really doing the same thing.

Comment: @aschepler Thank you. Would you show me an example?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Thank you. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, two small corrections.

(There's probably no need to edit the question again. I think the site allows only a limited number of edits, so it's best to reserve them for cases of real need! The question is now just about clear enough as it stands.)

(1) The quantities $\eta_{i0}$ ($i = 0, 1, \ldots, n$) and $\eta_{0j}$ are not variables.

(2) Some indices in the $n \times n$ matrix for $\eta$ have been mistyped.

Replacing $n$ with $n + 1,$ for simplicity, and calling the matrix $\tilde{\eta}$ instead of $\eta,$ we have:
\begin{equation}
\tilde{\eta} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \tfrac{n}{n+1} & \tfrac{n-1}{n+1} && \cdots && \tfrac1{n+1} \\
\tfrac{n}{n+1} & \eta_{11} & \eta_{12} && \cdots && \eta_{1n} \\
\tfrac{n-1}{n+1} & \eta_{21} & \eta_{22} && \cdots && \eta_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots && \vdots && \vdots \\
\tfrac1{n+1} & \eta_{n1} & \eta_{n2} && \cdots && \eta_{nn} \\
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^{(n+1)\times(n+1)}.
\end{equation}

I suggest ordering the variable elements of the matrix $\tilde{\eta}$ as
the vector $\eta \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^{n^2},$ where:
$$
\eta = (\eta_{11}, \eta_{22}, \ldots, \eta_{nn}, \eta_{12}, \eta_{23}, \ldots, \eta_{n-1,n}, \eta_{13}, \ldots, \eta_{1n}, \eta_{21}, \eta_{32}, \ldots, \eta_{n,n-1}, \eta_{31}, \ldots, \eta_{n1}).
$$
That is: start with the main diagonal, then list the diagonals in order towards the top right corner, then the remaining diagonals in order towards the bottom left corner.

For example, if $n = 3$ (or in your terms, $n = 4$):
$$
\tilde{\eta} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \tfrac34 & \tfrac12 & \tfrac14 \\
\tfrac34 & \eta_{11} & \eta_{12} & \eta_{13} \\
\tfrac12 & \eta_{21} & \eta_{22} & \eta_{23} \\
\tfrac14 & \eta_{31} & \eta_{32} & \eta_{33} \\
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^{4\times4}, \, \text{ and } \,
\eta = (\eta_{11}, \eta_{22}, \eta_{33}, \eta_{12}, \eta_{23}, \eta_{13}, \eta_{21}, \eta_{32}, \eta_{31}) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^9.
$$
In this case, I think we can write the integral in one (long!) line as:
\begin{multline*}
I = \int_0^{\tfrac34}
\int_0^{\min\left\{\tfrac12, \eta_{11}\right\}}
\int_0^{\min\left\{\tfrac14, \eta_{22}\right\}} \\
\int_{\eta_{22}}^{\min\left\{\tfrac12, \eta_{11}\right\}}
\int_{\eta_{33}}^{\min\left\{\tfrac14, \eta_{22}\right\}}
\int_{\eta_{23}}^{\min\left\{\tfrac14, \eta_{12}\right\}}
\int_{\eta_{22}}^{\min\left\{\tfrac12, \eta_{11}\right\}}
\int_{\eta_{33}}^{\min\left\{\tfrac14, \eta_{22}\right\}}
\int_{\eta_{32}}^{\min\left\{\tfrac14, \eta_{21}\right\}}
\\ f(\eta)
\,d\eta_{31}\,d\eta_{32}\,d\eta_{21}
\,d\eta_{13}\,d\eta_{23}\,d\eta_{12}
\,d\eta_{33}\,d\eta_{22}\,d\eta_{11}.
\end{multline*}

For $n = 2$ (in your terms, $n = 3$), it's a bit simpler:
\begin{gather*}
\tilde{\eta} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \tfrac23 & \tfrac13 \\
\tfrac23 & \eta_{11} & \eta_{12} \\
\tfrac13 & \eta_{21} & \eta_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^{3\times3}, \, \text{ and } \,
\eta = (\eta_{11}, \eta_{22}, \eta_{12}, \eta_{21}) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^4; \\
I = \int_0^{\tfrac23}\int_0^{\min\left\{\tfrac13, \eta_{11}\right\}}
\int_{\eta_{22}}^{\min\left\{\tfrac13, \eta_{11}\right\}}
\int_{\eta_{22}}^{\min\left\{\tfrac13, \eta_{11}\right\}}
f(\eta)\,d\eta_{21}\,d\eta_{12}\,d\eta_{22}\,d\eta_{11}.
\end{gather*}

As an example, to make sure that nothing is too obviously broken, let's try to compute the volume of the region of integration for $n = 2,$ by taking $f(\eta) = 1$ for all $\eta$:
\begin{multline*}
V = \int_0^{\tfrac23}\int_0^{\min\left\{\tfrac13, \eta_{11}\right\}}
\left(\min\left\{\frac13, \eta_{11}\right\} - \eta_{22}\right)^2
\,d\eta_{22}\,d\eta_{11} =
\frac13\int_0^{\tfrac23}\min\left\{\frac13, \eta_{11}\right\}^3\,d\eta_{11}
\\ = \frac13\int_{\tfrac13}^{\tfrac23}\frac1{3^3}\,d\eta_{11} +
\frac13\int_0^{\tfrac13}\eta_{11}^3\,d\eta_{11}
= \frac1{3^5} + \frac1{4\times3^5} = \frac5{972}
\end{multline*}

Comment: For completeness, I should write out the iterated integral expression for general $n,$ and give something resembling a proof that it is equal to $\int f(\eta)\,d\eta$ for $\eta$ satisfying the specified inequalities. (By the way, the point of criticism (1) is that if the integral expression in the question were taken literally, it would be an integral over an $(n-1)^2$-dimensional region of $n^2$-dimensional space, evaluating to $0.$) I'll try to do this tomorrow. I don't know any text(s) to refer to, so I'll have to wing it a bit, but I'm fairly sure that everything can be justified formally.